# DateTimeControl position issue

Tags: calendar, jquery-ui, datetimecontrol

I am trying to add DateTimeControl to my webform dynamically within a Panel which is preparing form fields dynamically. The form is long and placed on a jquery tab and have added scroll bar by restricting the height of the tab control.

The DateTimeControl is getting added fine, the issue is that after clicking on calender icon to pick the date, that calendar is getting popped up outside the tab page much below it. Basically that iframe is taking absolute "top" position ignoring the fixed height of tab page whereas it should have taken relative position.

It would be great if you could share some pointers, your views on how can one control positioning of that calendar iframe...

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that the html element that the datetime control is in has the css property:

```
position:relative;
```

That ensures that the absolute positioning of the element inside it will be relative to its container.

Comment: Thanks, it did resolve my issue. Sorry for the late response!

Comment: @ManojPatil if it solves the issue, please accept the answer.. which will help others